# how to display ajax response to a <div> inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to edit comment box, so there are many users to comment to a post. Each user can edit their comments. The comments are fetched from database and for each the comments written to a  `<div class="view-comment">`.

My issues is that the single edit result displays in all comment fields. I think it's because of the code inside a loop. How can I change them separately?

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $row)  
{ 
  $comment = $row["comment"];
  $username = $row["username"]; ?>

  <div class="view-coment" ">
    <div class="comment-padd">
      <div class="comments">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="coment-lft">
              <?php if($comment) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/avatar/<?php echo $username ;?>.jpg" class="img-response">
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <h2><?php echo $row['username'];?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['comment'];?></p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php if ($username == $this->session->userdata('username') ){ ?>
        <div class="comments-edit">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class=" dropdown-toggle" id="cmnt"><i class="fa fa-angle-down " aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu-5" aria-labelledby="cmnt">
              <input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" />
              <button class="my_button" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >edit</button>
```

```js
$('button.my_button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();     
  var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  // alert(id);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url('home/comment_edit'); ?>',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      $('.view-coment').html(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Where is the `button.my_button` element? How does it relate to the `.view-coment`?

Comment: I can see the button in the edit now, but note that your HTML is invalid. You've got several mis-matched tags, and the child of a `ul` must be an `li`, not an `input` and `button`

Comment: sorry i didn't copied full. now i gave my html page with my_button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sooraj subramanyan as menstion by @Rory McCrossan please correct your html first. Then you can make your comment box unique as follow.

```
<div class="view-coment" id="comment_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

and in your js update the comment box with this

```
$('#comment_'+id).html(data);
```